# iterating images in a picturebox

Tags: c#

I'm looping through images using a PictureBox. I'm using a Panel, placing my PictureBox inside the Panel. Every time I put a new image I clear the 
panel. If I do this the pictures start flickering. How do I stop the flickering?

Comment: Canavar: any reason for undoing most of my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than clearing the panel and creating a new `PictureBox`, why not keep the same `PictureBox` but change the `Image` property to reflect the new image you want to display?